# Ayuda necesito Construir una subrutina que permita invertir el contenido de un arreglo de N casillas

Tags: pseint

¿Porque esta mal? ayuda me siento frustrado y estancado porque algo que parece ser tan simple no me salga. Necesito consejos de ustedes como programadores experimentados me siento inutil.

```
SubProceso respuesta <- inversion (N)
    Definir arreglo, i como entero;

    i<-0;
    para i<-0 hasta N con paso -1 Hacer
        arreglo[i]<- Azar(40);
    FinPara
Fin SubProceso

Proceso principal
    Dimension arreglo[N];

    Definir arreglo, N, i como entero;

    i<-0;

    Escribir 'ingresa la cantidad de numeros';
    Leer N;

    para i<-0 hasta N-1 con paso 1 Hacer
        arreglo[i]<-azar(40);
        Escribir arreglo[i];
    FinPara


    Para i<-0 hasta N-1 hacer
        inversion(N);
    FinPara
FinProceso
```

Answer (score 0):

Es la primera vez que veo un lenguaje en español jajaja. No lo conozco pero según mi lógica yo haría esto:

**para** i<-0 hasta N - 1 con paso 1 Hacer

```
aux[i] <- arreglo[(N - 1) - i];
```

**FinPara**

De esta forma por ejempo si N=4...

aux[0] = arreglo[3];

aux[1] = arreglo[2];

aux[2] = arreglo[1];

aux[3] = arreglo[0];

Answer (score 0):

**Primero**, hay que configurar PSeInt para que acepte arreglos de capacidad variable
**Segundo** tienes que pasarle el arreglo al SubProceso respuesta (recordar que no existen variables globales en PseInt)
**Tercero**, estás aplicando nuevamente la función azar para invertir el arreglo, cuando debes invertir el arreglo, no sobre asignarle números al azar
**Cuarto** Un arreglo, tanto para leerse como para escribirse solo se recorre una vez.
**Quinto** inversión es un proceso sin retorno, no devuelve ningún valor, la variable que declaraste no tiene ningún sentido ya que nunca toma ningún valor y por lo tanto va a mostrar un cero en la pantalla.

```
SubProceso inversion (arreglo,N)
    Definir i Como Entero;
    Para i<-N-1 Hasta 0 Con Paso -1  Hacer
        Escribir arreglo[i];
    FinPara
FinSubProceso

Proceso Principal
    Definir arreglo, i, N Como Enteros;

    Escribir "ingresa la cantidad de numeros";
    Leer N;

    Dimension arreglo[N];

    Para i<-0 Hasta N-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        arreglo[i]<-azar(40);
        Escribir arreglo[i];
    FinPara

    Escribir "";
    Escribir "Arreglo invertido:";
    Escribir "";

    inversion(arreglo,N);

FinProceso
```